# generacion y envio de array php por post

Tags: php, mysql, array, post

Tengo una consulta mysql:

```
while ($qry = mysql_fetch_array($res)){

  $id_prod = $qry["id"];
  $id_venta = $qry["id_venta"];
  $idcl = $qry["id_cl"];
  $garzon = $qry["usuario"];
  $valor_total = $qry["valor"]; 
  $prod= $qry['producto']; --> esta puede tener uno o mas valores
}
```

lo que necesito con esta consulta, generar un array de $prod, enviarla y recibirla por post en otra pagina. lo que me devuelve dicha variables es Array.
he intentado con varias opciones pero ninguna funciona.
entre ellas:

```
$data = array(); 
$data[$qry['producto']] = $qry['producto'];
```

y enviarla en formulario asi:

```
<input type="hidden" name="prod[]" value="<?=$data?>" >
```

y recibiendo asi (ejecutor.php)

```
$prod = $_POST["prod"];

$i = 1;
foreach ($prod as $e)
{
    echo "<br>".$e;
    $i++;
}
```

he leido y probado bastantes alternativas y ninguna funciona como deberia.
como mencione anteriormente, la variable $data puede tener 1 a X registros, por ejemplo:
el producto 1 puede vender 1 a X cantidad.
el producto 2 puede vender 1 cantidad.
y asi con uno o mas productos por ventas.
espero puedan orientarme.

Comment: deberias de mostrar que te trae el echo de $data te aseguro que te devuelve array, debes parsearlo a string

Comment: @JackNavaRow me devuelve Array, se me olvido ponerlo en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**valida tu consulta**
mira este es un ejemplo  que acabo de hacer yo
html envias a tu controlador o modelo  no se como lo estes haciendo

```
       <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label class="control-label">Experiencia</label>
            <select class="form-control input-sm selectpicker" name="Datos[experiencia]" data-error="Es un campo obligatorio" required="required" id="experiencia">                           
                  <option value="ninguna">ninguna</option>
                  <option value="6 meses" selected="selected">6 meses</option>
                  <option value="1 año">1 año</option>
                  <option value="2 años">2 años</option>
                  <option value="5 años">3 años</option>
            </select>
          </div>
```

en el contralador recibo y envio de nuevo a la vista

```
$resultado = $this->varPerfil ->guardar($_POST["Datos"]);
```

modelo recibo parametro de array y devuelvo el resultado de la consulta al controlador

```
public function guardar($datos){
$experiencia = $this->conexion -> real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($datos["experiencia"])))); //escapar caracteres

$consulta = "INSERT INTO spartodo_rh.tblPerfiles (`experiencia`) VALUES ('$experiencia')";
}
```

aqui esta otro estoy guardando los (id) del select como string en la base de datos hac campo habilidades 1,2,3,4,5

```
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Habilidades</label>
            <select class="form-control input-sm selectpicker" name="habilidades[]" multiple data-error="Es un campo obligatorio" data-live-search="true" required="required" id="habilidades">
              <?php foreach ($habilidades as $habilidad) {?> 
              <option value="<?php echo $habilidad['idHabilidades']; ?>"><?php echo $habilidad['habilidad']; ?></option>
              <?php } ?>
            </select>
          </div>
```

controlador

```
$resultado = $this->varPerfil -> guardar($_POST["habilidades"]);
```

modelo

```
    public function guardar($habilidad){
    $habilidad = implode(",", $habilidades);
                $habilidad = $this->conexion -> real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($habilidad))));

$consulta = "INSERT INTO spartodo_rh.tblPerfiles (`habilidad`) VALUES ('$habilidad')";
    }
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda. tu ejemplo me servira de referencia para otro modelo que necesito desarrollar. saludos

Comment: si te fue util la respuesta podrias seleccionar en la fecha que fue utili la respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Hay muchas formas de hacer esto pero te mostrare la comun y para mi la mas rapida

**1.- Puedes hacer un for de la variable y guardarlos en tu campo hidden**

```
for ($i = 0;i<count($data); $i++){
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="prod[]" value="'.$data[$i].'" >';
}
```

**2.-Serializando el array**

como todo se sabe en la programacion hay otras formas mas practicas

```
<input type="hidden" name="result" value="<?php echo  base64_encode(serialize($data)); ?>">
```

y cuando lo recibes lo deserializa ahorrandote el for

```
$producto = ( unserialize(base64_decode($_POST['result'])); );
```

> El base64 esta para evitar problemas con la comilla doble

Comment: perfecto.. adapte a lo que necesito y funciono. gracias por tu ayuda. saludos.

Comment: funcionó perfecto! sólo una duda. Existe algún límite en cuanto a la cantidad de info que se puede enviar en un input por post?

Comment: si!, creo lo maximo son 3MB de igual forma lo puedes cambiar en el php.ini POST_MAX_SIZE, y tambien puede que te toque modificar algun valor de apache/nginx, igual no creo que cargues tantos datos como para que te veas en la necesidad de incrementar el valor

Answer (score 0):

### Primero

Tienes que asegurarte de que la consulta está trayendo datos.

### Segundo

Declara el array antes del `while`:

```
$data=array();
```

### Tercero

Llena el array dentro del `while`, así:

```
while ($qry = mysql_fetch_array($res)){

  $data['id'] = $qry["id"];
  $data['id_venta'] = $qry["id_venta"];
  $data['id_cl'] = $qry["id_cl"];
  $data['usuario'] = $qry["usuario"];
  $data['valor'] = $qry["valor"]; 
  $data['producto'] = $qry['producto']; --> esta puede tener uno o mas valores
}

/*Si esto no muestra nada, tienes problemas con tu consulta*/
var_dump($data);
```

### Cuarto

Puedes serializar el array para enviarlo:

```
<input type="hidden" name="prod[]" value="<?=htmlspecialchars(serialize($data));?>" >
```

### Quinto

En el archivo que recibe, puedes usar `unserialize` para recuperar el array.

```
$datos = unserialize($_POST['prod']);
print_r($datos);
//Trabaja con tus datos como quieras...
```