# Como asignar un array creado con Jquery a un Input para pasarlo por Post

Tags: jquery, array, post

Tengo un array que fue creado con Jquery y necesito enviar ese array por medio de un formulario (Post). Luego de crearse el array, lo imprimo por consola y veo el array creado correctamente. El mismo tiene dos elementos que corresponden a los IDs de articulos.
*nota: este array podría llegar a contener n elementos, es tan solo para la consulta que tan solo tiene dos elementos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado dos formas de asignarlo a un Input para enviarlo por medio de un formulario pero ninguna con exito en la recepcion del array.

Lo primero que he probado es lo siguiente

```js
$('input#orden').val(orden);
```

Recibo los datos en un archivo PHP, por lo que para verificar lo que he recibido, ejecuto un var_dump(). Y esto es lo que me muestra

```html
array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "30,29" }
```

Del array inicial con dos elementos "30" y "29" recibo un array con un solo elemento "30,29", en el cual se concatenaron los dos elementos iniciales separados por una coma

Lo segundo que he probado es

```js
$('input#orden').val((i) => orden[i]);
```

En este caso al hacer ejecutar el var_dump() para ver lo que recibo, veo esto

```html
array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "30" }
```

En el array recibo solo el primer elemento, de los dos que se envió.

Necesito recibir todos los elementos del array enviado y que no esten concatenados, puesto que luego de recibirlo tengo que recorrer ese array

Comment: Quizás si le hechas un ojo a esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/136839/generacion-y-envio-de-array-php-por-post ,  y este otro esta muy interesante :  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/221377/pasar-un-array-mediante-un-post-usando-javascript-o-jquery

Comment: Puedes enviarlo mediante Ajax directamente, o usando la nueva API Fetch de Javascript. De hecho, es la forma actual de pasar datos al servidor actualmente, porque entre otras cosas, no necesitas recargar la página para verificar una eventual respuesta de vuelta del servidor.